# Change flex skin before application is displayed

Tags: apache-flex, skinning

I'm trying to completly externalize skins in my flex application. I have created swf file based on css files and I want to apply one skin before application is initialized otherwise I obtain error like this :

> Error: Required skin part serverTimer cannot be found.

I have found this link : [here](http://userflex.wordpress.com/2008/02/07/preload-runtime-styles/) but it does not seem to work (any longer) and I think it's a bit dirty way.

So how can I load skin for my app before application initialization please ?

Comment: Search for "custom preloader" or something like that: you can create a custom preloader which delays the initialization of the application.

Comment: Thank you, I was justly reading some articles on it. I think it will solve my problem

Comment: ok here is an interesting link to achieve what I want to do : http://npacemo.com/wordpress/2008/07/06/flex-application-bootstrapping-totally-custom-preloader/